# How to include SharePoint assemblies in EXE after publishing

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015

I have developed a simple .EXE in Visual Studio 2015, which adds an item to the specified SharePoint site and List when the user runs some process.

The file is saved in a shared network drive, and everything seems to work perfectly except for one detail.

I can't seem to work out how to run the EXE without having the following .dll files saved in the same folder:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll
```

If I move these from the folder in which the EXE is saved in, I get this error message when running the exe:

`Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Couldt not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral ... Or one of its dependencies ...`

I (think) I have set up 'strong named assembly' by following [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41(v=vs.110).aspx) instructions in VS for the app, and I was able to add the SharePoint dlls to the GAC by using the VS command line and gacutil.exe (with a successful confirmation message), but I am still unable to run the EXE without having the 2 .dll files present.

Note: I developed the app to target .NET-4, but the users will be accessing the files from a system with .NET-3.5 installed, however the server on which the EXE is saved on does have the .NET-4 environment.

Comment: If you run the exe from network path from another PC this PC must have the dll's on the GAC folder or on the same folder of the exe. In short the GAC have the precedence before the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using a tool called `ILMerge` which can be found [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) and is available as a NuGet package.

ILMerge allows you to merge dlls and exe files into a single exe